# My web project zooming picture is not working on android device but ios is nice

Tags: angularjs, html, scroll, ionic-framework, zooming

1. My project used ionicframework, the image zooming is useing H5's tag scroll & div.
2. This is my js & Html code..
3. can you help me ?
4. I will be vary grateful

```js
  app.register.directive('zoomable', function(scroll) {
         return {
             link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                 element.bind('load', function() {
                     var container = document.getElementById(scope.item.id);
                     var clientWidth = 0;
                     var clientHeight = 0;
 
                     var scroller = new Scroller(scroll.render(container), {
                         scrollingX: true,
                         scrollingY: true,
                         animating: true,
                         bouncing: true,
                         locking: true,
                         zooming: true,
                         minZoom: false,
                         maxZoom: 1.5
                     });
 
                    
                     var rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
                     scroller.setPosition(rect.left + container.clientLeft, rect.top + container.clientTop);
                     var image = document.getElementById(scope.item.id);
                     var contentWidth = image.width;
                     var contentHeight = image.height;
                     var reflow = function() {
                         clientWidth = container.clientWidth;
                         clientHeight = container.clientHeight;
                         scroller.setDimensions(clientWidth, clientHeight, contentWidth, contentHeight);
                     };
                     window.addEventListener("resize", reflow, false);
                     reflow();
                     if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
                         container.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
                             if (e.touches[0] && e.touches[0].target &&
 e.touches[0].target.tagName.match(/input|textarea|select/i)) {
                                 return;
                             }
                             scroller.doTouchStart(e.touches, e.timeStamp);
                             e.preventDefault();
                         }, false);
                         document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
                             scroller.doTouchMove(e.touches, e.timeStamp, e.scale);
                         }, false);
                         document.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
                             scroller.doTouchEnd(e.timeStamp);
                         }, false);
                         document.addEventListener("touchcancel", function(e) {
                             scroller.doTouchEnd(e.timeStamp);
                         }, false);
                     } else {
                         var mousedown = false;
                         container.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
                             if (e.target.tagName.match(/input|textarea|select/i)) {
                                 return;
                             }
                             scroller.doTouchStart([{
                                 pageX: e.pageX,
                                 pageY: e.pageY
                             }], e.timeStamp);
                             mousedown = true;
                         }, false);
                         document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
                             if (!mousedown) {
                                 return;
                             }
                             scroller.doTouchMove([{
                                 pageX: e.pageX,
                                 pageY: e.pageY
                             }], e.timeStamp);
                             mousedown = true;
                         }, false);
                         document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
                             if (!mousedown) {
                                 return;
                             }
                             scroller.doTouchEnd(e.timeStamp);
                             mousedown = false;
                         }, false);
                         container.addEventListener(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > -1
 ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel", function(e) {
                             scroller.doMouseZoom(e.detail ? (e.detail * -120) : e.wheelDelta, e.timeStamp, e.pageX, e.pageY);
                         }, false);
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
     })
```

```html
 
    <ion-slide-box>
       <ion-slide  ng-repeat="item in imageInfo.works" >
           <div id="{{item.id}}"  class="big_img_show box" style="width:100%">
             <img ng-src="{{item.img}}" zoomable id="{{item.id}}" on-hold="savePhoto()" style="width:100%;">
           </div>
     </ion-slide>
   </ion-slide-box >
```

Comment: What did you try? The question doesn't provide much of details and might be hard to answer.

Comment: yes i'll help you come to my place taking your project

Comment: Thanks for your time, I have added some my question's detail..@Co.Aden @Klaster_1

Comment: @HeroNunchaku What do you mean with `My web project zooming picture is not working on android device but ios is nice`? Can you provide screenshots of both devices?